# Unresolved reference displaying in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-2

I am using `room persistence library` and `dagger`

**RoomModule.kt**

```
@Module
class RoomModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideMoviesAppDatabase(application: Application): MoviesAppDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder<MoviesAppDatabase>(application, KtMoviesAppDatabase::class.java, Keys.DATABASE_NAME)
                .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {}
                    override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {}
                })
                .build()
    }

}
```

**KtMoviesAppDatabase.kt**

```
@Database(entities = [Movie::class], version = 1)
abstract class KtMoviesAppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getMovieDAO(): MovieDAO
}
```

**Error I am getting:**

[image]

---

### {EDIT}

I made some changes

```
@Module
class RoomModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideMoviesAppDatabase(application: Application): KtMoviesAppDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder<KtMoviesAppDatabase>(application, KtMoviesAppDatabase::class.java, Keys.DATABASE_NAME)
                .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {}
                    override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {}
                })
                .build()
    }

}
```

**Still I have the error :**

```
Unresolved reference: java
```

Comment: remove `.java`  , that should work i guess

Comment: If i remove `.java` we will get error  Type mismatch.`
`Required:
Class<TypeVariable(T)!>
Found:
KClass<KtMoviesAppDatabase>`

Comment: What is `MoviesAppDatabase` ? , also  sorry `.java` is needed there

Comment: Your return statement should return a `KtMoviesAppDatabase` but you are taking it as `MoviesAppDatabase`

Comment: @ManoharReddy ... I made some changes ....Please check the edit

Comment: Wild guess, but try removing "<KtMoviesAppDatabase>" part from "Room.databaseBuilder<KtMoviesAppDatabase>". It should work without it, since compiler sees from method's return type what should be got there.

Comment: @SadClown ...would get the error as `Type expected`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very Silly mistake since I had not added proper dependencies

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error earlier time and I solved this problem by updating the android studio
you can update using this path (help > check for updates...)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33684543)